# Getting Data from Firestore User in Home Page

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get UserData from the Firestore database. I'm currently doing it with a Steam Provider, inside this Steam provider is all my home page, I will like to be able to use the data from firestore inside my home page.

Heres the home page code:

```
return StreamProvider<List<usuariodata>>.value(
      value: DatabaseService().dadosusuarios,
      child: Scaffold(
      ...
```

Heres how I'm gathering stuff, from another file:

```
class DatabaseService {
//Colection reference
final String uid;
DatabaseService({this.uid});

final CollectionReference userdata = 
Firestore.instance.collection('dadosusuarios');

//dados usuario snapshot
List<usuariodata> _usuariosListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
return snapshot.documents.map((doc){
  return usuariodata(
    name: doc.data['name'] ?? '',
    sensores: doc.data['sensores'] ?? '',
    led1: doc.data['led1'] ?? false,
    quantidade: doc.data['quantidade'] ?? 0,
    );
  }).toList();
 }

Stream<List<usuariodata>> get dadosusuarios {
return userdata.snapshots()
.map(_usuariosListFromSnapshot);
}
}
```

I would be able to call it from another page like this:

```
final data = Provider.of<<List<usuariodata>>(context);
data.forEach((data) {
  print(data.name);
  ...
)};
```

**But since this is supposed to be used in another page, how could I gather the info from my firestore database and store it into usable variables before my main page shows.**

Answer (score 0):

i suggest to get the data real-time using Firestore in a stream directly. no providers needed. for example

```
return Center(
         child : StreamBuilder(
                  stream : Firestore.instance.collection('dadosusuarios').snapshots(),
                  builder : ((context,data){
                 return //Your Widget 
                 }),
                ....
```

Comment: but how would I be able to acess the stuff from my collection?, I need to store it?

Comment: no. that 'data' is a async snapshot. whole collection is inside of that data async snpashot. 
you can access it simply,  data.data.document[index of the document as aint][field name as a string]

Comment: For some reason I can`t add the stream builder, it keeps asking for a ) and ; all the time, but I have added it

Comment: its not the complete code just a example. here is a quick gist i made https://gist.github.com/SrilalS/f7ef7a0fb3a55544b8f7a08ca300eba8

if you need more explanations read this : https://medium.com/@srilalsachintha/using-flutter-streams-with-firestore-database-15f3b1322090

Comment: you don't have to. that is just a example. you whole collection is inside the 'data' object. use is the way you want.

Comment: Ok, but when I do this data.data.document[index of the document as aint][field name as a string] how can i get the [index of the document as aint] according to the user that's logged in?